# Docker unable to connect and download the image files

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up Docker on Windows 10 machine and facing this issue.

1. When I try running "docker run hello-world", the following error is returned.

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally docker: Error
> response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unable
> to connect to 54.242.59.189:443. Do you need an HTTP proxy?. See
> 'docker run --help'.

2. I tried setting up a proxy, via a VirtualBoxVM Linux on my system, and squid proxy on it. It returns a similar error.

> Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally docker:
> Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/":
> unable to connect to HTTP proxy 192.168.150.107:3128. See 'docker run
> --help'.

3. I have tried running Dockers on my other machine (Mac) and it works fine and is able to get the images. This shows that there is no issue with the network.
4. I installed VirtualBox and Ubuntu on windows. I tried to run docker on the LInuxVM and this also works and is able to connect and get the images.
5. I also tried configuring proxy server address in the config.json but "docker info" still shows the proxy server as "http.docker.internal:3128". And still give the same error.
6. I also tried configuring DNS address in the config.json. And still, gives the same error.

Please suggest what else can be blocking docker. How can I get Docker to run on my system?

Thanks
Aadhaar

Comment: Can some system firewall or antivirus like windows defender block the address?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The outgoing connection was blocked by Window's firewall.

If you have the same cause you can solve it by allowing `com.docker.vpnkit.exe` through:

1. Start `Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security`.
2. Right-click on `Outbound Rules` and click `New Rule...`.
3. Select `Program`, click `Next`.
4. Browse to `%ProgramFiles%\Docker\Docker\resources` and find `com.docker.vpnkit.exe`, click `Next`.
5. Select `Allow the connection`, click `Next`.
6. Apply to appropriate profiles, click `Next`.
7. Give it a name and click `Finish`.